# Multiple ids with getElementById();

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm trying to get javascript to write html on a page when a link is clicked.

```
function updatetext(){
    var file = document.getElementById("file").value;
document.getElementById('updated').innerHTML = file;
}
<input id="file" value="text I want to write to the page" type="hidden">
<span id="updated">&nbsp;</span>
```

This works for an ID labeled "file" but I have multiple ID's like, file1, file2, file3...

I'm wondering if my onclick="updatetext()"; should have some argument like onclick="updatetext(1)"; but that doesn't seem to work.  I'm not sure how to get the right input id from clicking on the link.

Comment: Yes, an argument should work. Could you please show us the code you tried?

Comment: Actually, the OP's IDs are quite unique. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function updatetext(id){
    var file = document.getElementById("file" + id).value;
    document.getElementById('updated').innerHTML = file;
}
```

That should do it, if you want to do what I interpreted

Comment: You can't have `var` inside the parenthesis... has to be `function updatetext(id)`

Comment: Warning, personal preference: I would use the full id as the parameter and then it becomes `getElementById(id)`. I find that easier to work with in the long run.

Comment: @JeffShaver Thanks.  New to web development obviously lol.  That worked perfectly.